# Last reboot shown few rows at the same time?

Tags: logs, reboot, last

I had got this from my server logs. I wonder what does it mean by that? ("Last reboot", The repetition of the same day and time)

```
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-35-generi Fri Jul 10 17:15 - 12:06  (18:51)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-35-generi Fri Jul 10 16:56 - 12:06  (19:10)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-35-generi Fri Jul 10 11:11 - 12:06 (1+00:55)
```

Comment: Take a look at the `last` man page, it's covered in there.

Comment: @slm ,I just did a read through via `man last`. There is nothing explain last reboot repetition in the same day and time means. Can you explain more? Thanks

Comment: Could be a bug. If you run `last | grep reboot | head -3` do you see times that are not 12:06? What distribution and version are you running?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick when I do grep with head-3 there are one more on top `reboot   system boot  3.13.0-35-generi Sat Jul 11 12:07 - 10:04 (4+21:56)` My distribution is Ubuntu 14.04